# In javascript/html, how can I get a part of an external website (such as a div) and set it onto mine?

Tags: javascript, html, copy, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a google chrome extension using javascript/html. Currently, I'm simply trying to make a page that has a div exactly the same as another website's div. So for example in Google Translate, for the following link: http://translate.google.com/, there is a div: `<div id="gog"> ... </div>` and in my html page, I have a div: name="output"> ...imitate "gog" div in here... </div>. How can I copy all the contents of "gog" into "output" using javascript. Is this not possible? Any example would be great!

**Note** that I'm not making this for Google translate so accessing their api isn't a viable option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at jQuery's load() function:
http://api.jquery.com/load/

As you can see there

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

would load the content of #container on 'ajax/test.html' into #result on the current page.

Answer (score 0):

Get the two divs in the shape of dom objects ([here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp)) and then use the innerHtml to move the innards of gog to the innards of output. Does that answer your question?